# IBM Cloud Private (ICP) Community Edition - License Restrictions

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

Can IBM Cloud Private (ICP) Community Edition be used for production workloads (where is license text)?

Comment: Off topic as licensing question and/ or asking for a resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ICP Community Edition is licensed under IBM's license for Non-Warranted code. It is not intended for production use so there is no paid support option and you can only have a single master node. The licenses are posted here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/W1559b1be149d_43b0_881e_9783f38faaff/page/Licenses

Answer (score 0):

You can used ICP CE as on your risk if you used ICP CE for production.

It has not restriction in term of license to run